# Exit code 256 in Pascal on Mac OS X 10

Tags: macos, compiler-errors, pascal, lazarus

I just have installed Lazarus on my MacBook Air with OS X 10. And when I want to run a code, it says

> Exit code 256

Does anyone know, what should I do?

Comment: Not very much to work with. Exit code 256 is no general pascal runtime error (which is also returned on exit)

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort: I get the same as ***compiler error*** if I try to build or run a very simple console program: `program HelloWorld; begin Writeln('Hello, world'); end.`. The error is `Compile Project, Target: HelloWorld: Exit code 256, Errors: 1 -- Fatal: Compilation aborted`. And there is indeed nothing to go by. No indication what the error is, i.e. why it does not compile.

Comment: Then it goes into the realm of OS X versioning, which is beyond me, since I threw Mac under a bus after 10.5. I believe the strace/ktrace tool on OS X is called truss, and simply starting and debugging under GDB also might be beneficial

Comment: As I siad, it was a **compiler message**. This weekend, I installed macOS Sierra and after that, not much worked anymore. So I reinstalled fpc, fpcsrc and lazarus (which is not so easy anymore, on Sierra, since it is not in the AppStore and Sierra mistrusts apps not in the AppStore -- but I finally managed) and the error was gone.

Comment: My point (of the first comment) was more that after a quick grep, the FPC src don't seem to have 256 as an halt/runerror code, so it must be some spot where an OS error or external program returned it. Since FPC doesn't change with OS upgrade, Apple provided tools are a likely source if the fail starts after an upgrade (and also why clean reinstall fixed it (newer XCode?)). Anyway, the best remedy is monitor the mac-pascal list at pascal central. Problems due to Apple's OS X or XCode related breakages are usually discussed there quite fast. I do follow it a bit but have no system to test.

Answer (score 2):

### Explanation

I had the same problem. I tried to compile this extremely basic program:

```
program HelloWorld;

begin
  Writeln('Hello, world');
end.
```

And I got the error message:

```
Compile Project, Target: HelloWorld: Exit code 256, Errors: 1
Fatal: Compilation aborted
```

I think this was due to the fact that I had installed ***macOS Sierra*** last weekend. So I re-installed (with some difficulties, see below) the `fcp`, `fpcsrc` and `lazarus` packages and recompiled the source. Now I got a `success` message.

### Answer

So re-download the packages above (they may have longer names, but these are the base names). Then first install `fpc`, then `fpcsrc` and then `lazarus`. Note that if you simply double-click the `.pkg` files in the `.dmg` files, *macOS Sierra* will complain:

> “lazarus.pkg” can’t be opened because it is from an unidentified developer.

So open the context menu (right click) and select `Open`. Then you will get:

> “lazarus.pkg” is from an unidentified developer. Are you sure you want to open it?

Then you can click the <kbd>Open</kbd> button and it will start the installer anyway. Follow the instructions and all should install well.

After that, you should be able to compile your code without that ugly error message. Note that under OS X (or, as they call it now, macOS) you won't be able to debug console mode programs from the Lazarus IDE. You'll have to start it from the console.

Comment: So, I reinstalled the computer and it didn't work either. However, then I realized that I forgot about defining a variables. It works now. But when it is a simple program without variables... I don't know.